# Jenkins job is failing when i try to copy files to aws S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins

Jenkins job is failing when i try to copy files to aws S3 bucket

I make aws connection from jenkins console. Essentially I make copy files to S3 bucket. But it is not happening, my jenkins job is failing.
Can anyone please help in resolving the issue. I am going this from Execute shell section in jenkins.

```
aws s3 cp: ./lib s3://${bucketname}/$foldername --recursive
```

Comment: Please add an error message to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure a profile in jenkins box and give profile name in the command that you execute from the jenkins console

```
aws s3 cp: ./lib s3://${bucketname}/$foldername --recursive --profile <name of the profile>
```

Hope this will help.